# How to add new (third party) portlets, gadgets into Exo Platform Community Edition?

Tags: social-networking

We have installed Exo platform Community Edition.

What are possible ways to add new/third party plugins into Exo Community Edition, and what are dis/advantages of using particular method?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add your bundles into the corresponding folders (jar to lib, war to webapps), then using Application Management to make these portlets/gadgets visible to add to a page or your Dashboard. More detail is at http://docs.exoplatform.com/PLF41/PLFUserGuide.AdministeringeXoPlatform.ManagingApplications.html.